# IIS write permissions to web root

Tags: iis, permissions, windows-10, iis-10

I created IIS website with following setting (ApplicationPool account is named `Fitko`)

[image]

When I run website and submit form with image, application throw an error

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\IISWorkspace\Fitko\upload\instructors' is denied.
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)

I gave full permissions to `Fitko` folder to these accounts

- IUSR
- Users
- Administrators
- network service
- IIS AppPool\Fitko

yet still the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception still throwing.

How can I give access permissions to IIS to write to the folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue by enabling `windows authentication` (I had Anonymous Authentication before, but probably it can be enabled together)

[image]

the setting is in

`Web Project > Properties > Debug > Web Server Settings`

and the flag seems to takes control even when the publish configuration is set to release.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the issue typically indicates a permission error of the specific folder.
What is your Application pool identity? try to right-click the folder and grant `Everyone Account` full access to the folder.
[image]
Besides, under certain cases, this might relate to our website framework technology.
https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/issues/272
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thank you for a tip ! I gave full control to "Everyone" account, but the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is still throwing :/ I don't know Stryker, but it seems like a nice library. As a workaround I am just saving and retrieving images from database.

Comment: Can other web pages work properly, or just the uploading page does not work?  (since we save the image to a local disk)  In addition, please restart the website and clear the browser cache before testing the page.

Comment: Yes, other pages works fine, only the controller action which tries to save image to local disk throw this weird error. I restarted PC and IIS several times, also I hit F5 in browser to clear cache, but error was still there. But finally the problem is solved by enabling `Windows Authentication` in Project Name > Properties > Debug > Web Server Settings :-)

Answer (score 0):

In internet service manager right click on the default website, click on edit permission, click on the security tab the click on edit
Add built-in ISUR account to the website and give the appropriate access
and or add built in IIS_IUSERS account and do the same if the above does not work.